# Viewport for ipad portrait [only]

Tags: viewport

I have built a responsive website and it encounters problem while rendering in portrait orientation on iPad

i.e It doesn't correctly fit in.

I have tried adjusting the viewport meta's parameter values but that also affects the whole rendering, including on mobile.

I used the following viewport meta in my website.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue just now, on a site that is 1550px wide on desktop but only 880px on mobile.

Things were working great with

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=880px, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1;" />
```

combined with

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/css/base.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width:880px)" href="/css/mobile.css" />
```

(`mobile.css` readjust some element widths to fit nicely into the 880px mobile layout.)

Things looked good until I tested it on an iPad in the iOS Simulator. In portrait things looked alright, but in landscape orientation some elements (specifically those with `width: 100%`) adjusted to the viewport width, while some didn't (that one element with `width: 1550px`). This meant that when scrolling right (or zooming out) to view the entire 1550px element, the elements with `width: 100%` were left dangling from the left side, only about half as wide as they should be.

The solution was far from obvious, but here's how I solved it:

**base.css**

```
body{
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1550px; 
}
```

**mobile.css**

```
body{
    min-width: 100%; 
}
```

This explicitly sets the miniumum width of the `body` element to 1550px for all devices wider than 880px, *including tablets that take the viewport meta tag into account*.
When viewed on a mobile device with a width less than 880px, the width of the `body` element is reset to simply 100%, i.e. the viewport width.

Hope this will help someone out there struggling with different layouts for different devices.