# Understand Viewport for desktop,Ipad,tablet,cellphone for a site page

Tags: css, width, device, viewport, scaling

I am trying to understand how do we know if the user is coming to the website page from a **IPAD** **DEKTOP** or **PHONE**. I looked at few of the info on the internet but I still don't understand it very well here is what I know: from this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18769649/viewport-for-ipad-portrait-only)
do `<meta name="viewport" content="width=880px, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1;" />` return back what is the width of the device? how do I know which device its on and use that style-sheet?

Comment: No, the viewport does not return width, it set's the width of the browser. You would use css media queries based on screen width to write your css for the different screen sizes.

Comment: ohh I see so the `@media screen and (max-width: 600px)` is the query that see how big is the screen and then we know what to do with it

Comment: Yes exeactly... in the style sheet anything inside of `@media screen and (max-width: 600px) { CSS HERE }` will only be applied on screen sizes below 600px

Comment: Got so one more thing viewport if I like take it out not have it there would it effect at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use media queries (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to apply different styles. This is how responsive design works. It is not about applying different style sheets for different devices.

A media query could look like this :

```
p {font-size: 1em;}
@media (min-width: 30em) {
    p {font-size: 1.5em;}
}
```

Here for devices wider than 30em, the font size will be larger.

`meta viewport` is not for what you think, it is for setting the viewport width on a mobile device.